# trigger onchange event for span not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to trigger the onchange event on a span element. The event is not triggered at all. How can I make it happen? Here is my code:

First method I tried

```
  document.getElementById(seconds).addEventListener('change', (event: MutationEvent & { path: any }) => {
console.log('span has changed')
}
```

Second method

```
document.getElementById(seconds).onchange((event) => {
console.log('span has chanegd')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the onchange event only works on inputs, selects and textareas.
You will need another event.